# Configuring Unity using a file other than web.config or app.config?

Tags: unity-container

I understand how to configure MS Unity 2.0 using the app.config or web.config files. I want to instantiate the Unity Container and then somehow pass it the configuration file to use. The configuration file needs to be unrelated to the app.config or web.config (i.e. not a configuration section with a ConfigSource). Does anyone know if this can be done?

Comment: Never mind. Learned not to expect any help from Stack Overflow! I found the answer and you can just find yourself.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN is your friend: [Loading the Configuration from Alternative Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660935%28v=PandP.20%29.aspx#_Loading_the_Configuration)